# Azure Traffic Manager Endpoints show Degraded Even when 200 is Returned

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, azure-traffic-manager

I have an Azure Traffic Manager Profile with two Endpoints (Linux VM's running RabbitMQ).

The endpoints are of Type "*Azure Endpoint*" and the Target Resource Type is "*Public IP Address*".

When I look at the Traffic Manager Profile it reports that the Status of the profile is "*Enabled*", and the Monitor Status is "*Degraded*".

On Each of the endpoints it reports that their Status is "Enabled" and the Monitor Status is "Degraded".

I have the Traffic Manager Profile configured with Protocol as "HTTP" and Port as 15672 and the path as "/index.html".

The problem is I can't tell why it is reporting "Degraded" because if I do a wget command.

```
wget <vmname1>.cloudapp.azure.com:15672/index.html

Resolving <vmname1>.cloudapp.azure.com... <ip address>
Connecting to <vmname1>.cloudapp.azure.com|<ip address>|:15672... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1419 (1.4K) [text/html]
```

All the "documentation" (which for Azure is frustratingly just blog posts) says that if it returns 200 then it should be "Online" and not "Degraded".

Comment: what machine did you execute the wget from?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your reply, it is very likely that the issue is that the Traffic Manager health checks are being blocked by your NSG rules.

We don't have an easy way to configure Traffic Manager in NSGs today, nor do we publish the Traffic Manager health check source IP addresses.  These are gaps we are planning to fill.  In the meantime, the recommended workaround is to use a dedicated health check page running on a different TCP port for Traffic Manager, and apply the NSG only to the port used by your application.

Comment: I cannot configure a different port to do health checks on, because RabbitMQ only has 15672 for management and 5672 for actual activity. If i just configure a health check on some other random port for the server, that doesnt tell me if RabbitMQ is running.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded/), which may help you.

I can't be sure from the description you gave, but my best guess is that in your case the endpoint is returning a 301/302 redirect to a different URL, and the second URL is what is actually returning 200 OK.  Traffic Manager health probes don't support re-directs.  You can verify this for example using the F12 developer tools in IE.

Jonathan Tuliani, Program Manager, Azure Traffic Manager

Comment: wget (from my machine) is not reporting that there is any redirect being returned. In IE F12 developer tools it also reports result = 200 for the url. Is there any special Network Security Group rule that I need to add to maybe allow the Traffic Manager?

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case there's no good workaround available.  You can vote for the necessary feature on our feedback site, here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/3701574-publish-the-the-list-of-traffic-manager-probe-ips.  It's very high on our backlog.