# Azure Traffic Manager shows endpoints degraded but they return 200

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37426230/azure-traffic-manager-endpoints-show-degraded-even-when-200-is-returned), but I don't think it applies in my case.

I have two total endpoints that are both showing a status of "Degraded."

I read that this usually indicates that the monitor configuration is resulting in a response other than 200. However, testing with curl shows a 200 response for both endpoints. I initially had it set to probe the homepage (which also returned a 200), but added a dedicated 'probe' page just in case, which made no difference.

Here's my traffic manager configuration (classic portal, but that shouldn't matter):

[image]

Browser network inspector:

[image]

Here's my curl results:

[image]

Apparently if all endpoints are degraded, the traffic manager will still function, but I'm concerned that it may be affecting our geo-redundancy.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: this looks weird, can you try removing one endpoint and adding it back in?

Comment: I tried removing one and adding it back in and it's still labeled as 'Degraded.' I'm still only getting 200 responses from it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-L` in your `curl` invocation is for "follow redirects" which is throwing you off.

**[Traffic Manager won't follow HTTP redirects!](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-monitoring.md#endpoint-failover-and-recovery)**

Because your endpoints now return a `301 Moved Permanently` they are being rendered **Degraded**.

```sh
$ curl -Ii http://posguys-east.cloudapp.net/probe.html

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 147
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://posguys.com/probe.html
```

This is most probably because you have a HTTP → HTTPS redirect configured in your *web.config*.

The solution is simple, remove and re-add endpoints with `https://` instead.

#### LATER EDIT

It's not that simple, looks like your application is responding with a `301` redirect on `https://` too.

```sh
$ curl -kIiL https://posguys-east.cloudapp.net/probe.html
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 147
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://posguys.com/probe.html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=5184000
Content-Length: 149
Content-Type: text/html
```

You'll need to address that part. Add an exception for `/probe.html` to whatever rewrite rule you're hitting there. Test with `curl`, but no `-L` this time.

Comment: After running the same commands as you and still getting a 200 response, I discovered that we have rewrite exceptions for our internal IP addresses. No wonder this has been confusing to troubleshoot! I feel a bit silly, but thank you so much for indirectly pointing me in the right direction!